# How to queries in supabase realtime?

Tags: sql, postgresql, flutter, dart, supabase

Most of the blogs and stacks suggests below database for chat.

```
message_table
-id
-message
-conversationId
-sender
-receiverId

conversation_table
-id
-conversationId
```

Now `message_table` look like this.

[image]

So, for the chat screen I subscribe the message table.

```
final mySubscription = supabase
  .from('message_table')
  .on(SupabaseEventTypes.all, (payload) {
    // Handle realtime payload
  })
  .subscribe();
```

if user1 and user2 are chatting, they will get all messages from this table.

So, how to filter this data with specified conversationId in supabase to stop receive the other message of other users and for reduce of bandwidth ?

And Is this database viable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add eq filter on your realtime listeners like this:

#### supabase-flutter v1.X

```dart
final subscription = supabase.channel('unique_channel').on(
    RealtimeListenTypes.postgresChanges,
    ChannelFilter(
      event: '*',
      schema: 'public',
      table: 'message_table',
      filter: 'conversationId=eq.conv12',
    ), (payload, [ref]) {
      // handle realtime here
}).subscribe();
```

#### supabase-flutter v0.X

```dart
final subscription = supabase
  .from('message_table:conversationId=eq.conv12')
  .on(SupabaseEventTypes.all, (payload) {
    // Handle realtime payload
  })
  .subscribe();
```

You can read more about this feature on the official Supabase documentation [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/subscribe#listening-to-row-level-changes)!

Answer (score 0):

Finds all rows whose column satisfies the filter.

```
var conversationId = yourvalue ;
final mySubscription = supabase
  .from('message_table')
  .select('message, conversationId, sender , receiverId')
  .eq('conversationId', conversationId) // Correct
  .on(SupabaseEventTypes.all, (payload) {
    // Handle realtime payload
  })
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. We can't chain `.eq` and `.on`